# Need clarification on term "Module" in Swift

Tags: swift, module

I am new to Swift programming, and I am having a little trouble understanding the definition of a module. Apple's Swift documentation states:

> A module is a single unit of code distribution—a framework or application that is built and shipped as a single unit and that can be imported by another module with Swift’s import keyword.

The terminology above is confusing to me. Can someone explain in layman's terms of what a module in Swift is? Thank you for your patience :).

Comment: A module is a group of source code files that have been compiled together. That's all.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Is that it? Lol. Thank you! Why couldn't Apple just have said that. Anyways, thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: They probably did say that in the WWDC session videos somewhere... those are far more approachable than any written documentation. Whenever possible always watch those videos before doing any other research on Apple's developer tools. The documentation is just to give you the exact details of how everything works - it's not suitable as an overview.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert "group of source code files that have been compiled together" is a little vague, there is some packaging/headers, right? Is there support in Xcode to create Swift modules?

Comment: In Xcode term, a module is a Target.

Comment: @zaph sure, the "source code files compiled together" can *optionally* be stored in a directory that contains other stuff including headers or images or xib files or even other modules. But the primary purpose of a module is the source code compiled into it.

Comment: My interest is in creating my own modules to encapsulate portions of a large project in a similar manner as Java JARs.